# How to optimize the FFMPEG h264/aac conversion while generating HLS segments too

Tags: ffmpeg, red5, http-streaming

I am generating HLS segments using FFMPEG. Here is the command that I am using :

ffmpeg -i "rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/33/hlsopt3 live=1" -y -c:v libx264 -b:v 1000k -vprofile baseline -preset medium -x264opts level=41 -threads 4 -s 480x360 -map 0:v -c:a libfaac -b:a 160000 -ac 1 -hls_time 3 -hls_list_size 3 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 hlsopt3.m3u8

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 and using RED5 1.0.2 as my streaming server and I want to stream videos on android and ios devices. But the playback on devices is very jerky, they do not play video smoothly. Also my server's CPU utilization goes to more than 100%.

After so much research I have found that the CPU utilization is due to the H264/mpeg-4 aac conversion, But without doing conversion it wont play on Ios and android devices.

So please suggest me any solution. How I can play it smoothly on mobile devices and also save the CPU utilization.

Please help me I have almost waisted 10 days on this.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the reason why the FFMPEG used 100% of CPU and why jerky video displayed on devices. It is because I did not mentioned the frame rate.

**-r 24**

```
ffmpeg -i "rtmp://localhost/oflaDemo/33/hlsopt6 live=1" -y -c:v libx264 \
 -b:v 1000k -r 24 -vprofile baseline -preset medium -x264opts level=41 \
 -threads 4 -s 480x360 -map 0:v -c:a libfaac -b:a 160000 -ac 1 -hls_time 3 \
 -hls_list_size 2 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 hlsopt6.m3u8
```

Now it is playback smoothly on all devices and also FFMPEG take less CPU.

Comment: You generally do not need to declare an output frame rate: the output will simply use the same frame rate as the input. `ffmpeg` will simply drop or duplicate frames to reach your desired output frame rate.

Comment: Yes you are right But In case of streaming through RED5 If we do not put frame rate while converting the RTMP streamed video to H264/MPEG-4 Aac then the play back of the video is jerky. That's why it is required to define the output frame rate in FFMPEG.

Comment: I tested your command. Its output is on the files. Is there any way to send hls output as feed to webcaster servers?

Comment: @sajad just put to  your web server public folder example "/var/www/html"